# How can resolve NullPointerException Error in searchview using onQueryTextChange

Tags: android

**I have use SearchView in my application it also work fine when i enter one or two character but when i enter more character it show me  `NullPointerException` Error.**

**it show me Error onQueryTextChange(cardView1.java:251) and my 251 line code is:**

```
String name=object.title.toLowerCase();
```

**so please can you review my code and tell me how can i resolve this error. Please Help me :)**

My code is here.

File 1: **cardView1.java**

```
package com.ejobbox.ejobbox;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class cardView1 extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Model> list;
    private String baseURL="http://ejobbox.com/";
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Datakey";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME2 = "Updatekey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_view1);
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(cardView1.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        list=new ArrayList<Model>();
        // call retrofit

        // getRetrofit();

        adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerView, list,cardView1.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Store Data of UPDATE

        String UpdData= getIntent().getStringExtra("UpdResult");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I HAVE GOTE RESULT: "+UpdData,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME2,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editors=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editors.putInt("OldData", Integer.parseInt(UpdData));
        editors.apply();

        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
        Call<List<WPPost>> call= service.getPostInfo();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, final Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
                Log.e("mainactivty","response"+ response.body());

               /* // Badge Data Handling [START]

                int BadgeValue= response.body().size();

                sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editors=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editors.putInt("BadgeData", BadgeValue);
                editors.apply();

                String getBadgedata= String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("BadgeData",0));

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TOTAL DATA OF APP SIZE: "+getBadgedata,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Badge data Handaling [END]*/

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                for(int i=0; i<10;i++){

                    Log.e ("main","Title"+ response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered()+"  "+
                            response.body().get(i).getId());

                    String tempdetails=response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString();
                    tempdetails=tempdetails.replace("<p>","");
                    tempdetails=tempdetails.replace("</p>","");
                    String linkdetail=response.body().get(i).getLink().toString();
                    String date=response.body().get(i).getDate().toString();
                    String id=response.body().get(i).getId().toString();

                    //Date Adding

                    date=date.substring(0,10);

                    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    try {
                        Date date1 = fmt.parse(date);
                        SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        date=fmtOut.format(date1);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Excep"+e);
                    }

                    list.add(new Model(Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                            tempdetails,date,linkdetail,id));
                }


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //Load more data
                adapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onLoadMore() {
                        String dt="Load more Function Call";
                        Toast.makeText(cardView1.this, dt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (list.size() <= 30) {
                            list.add(null);
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
                                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(list.size());

                                    //Generating more data
                                    int index = list.size();
                                    int end = index + 10;
                                    for (int i = index; i < end; i++) {

                                        String dt="Data Load:"+i;
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),dt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        //data load more
                                        Log.e ("main","Title"+ response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered()+"  "+
                                                response.body().get(i).getId());

                                        String tempdetails=response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString();
                                        tempdetails=tempdetails.replace("<p>","");
                                        tempdetails=tempdetails.replace("</p>","");
                                        String linkdetail=response.body().get(i).getLink().toString();
                                        String date=response.body().get(i).getDate().toString();
                                        String id=response.body().get(i).getId().toString();
                                        //Date Adding

                                        date=date.substring(0,10);

                                        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                        try {
                                            Date date1 = fmt.parse(date);
                                            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                            date=fmtOut.format(date1);
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {
                                            System.out.println("Excep"+e);
                                        }

                                        list.add(new Model(Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                                                tempdetails,date,linkdetail,id));
                                    }
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    adapter.setLoaded();
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(cardView1.this, "Loading data completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
               finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.memu_items,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        //SearchView searchView=(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        newText=newText.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<Model> newList=new ArrayList<>();
        for(Model object:list)
        {

           String name=object.title.toLowerCase();
            if(name.contains(newText)) {
                newList.add(object);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"New Text:"+newText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        adapter.setFilter(newList);
        return true;
    }
}
```

File 2: **RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.ejobbox.ejobbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
    private boolean isLoading;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Model> dataset;
    private Context mContext;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    String getdata;
    String colorName="#4242f4";
    int myColor = Color.parseColor(colorName);

    String colorName2="#3bc600";
    int myColor2 = Color.parseColor(colorName2);





    public RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<Model> mlist, Context context) {


        this.dataset=mlist;
        this.mContext=context;
        this.activity=activity;


        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return dataset.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails,parent,false);
            return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemload,parent,false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ImageTypeViewHolder) {
            final Model object=dataset.get(position);
            final ImageTypeViewHolder imageTypeViewHolder=(ImageTypeViewHolder) holder;
            imageTypeViewHolder.title.setText(object.title);
            imageTypeViewHolder.subtitle.setText(object.subtitle);
            imageTypeViewHolder.link.setText(object.link);
            imageTypeViewHolder.date.setText(object.date);
            imageTypeViewHolder.id.setText(object.id);


            String myid=object.id;
            // Set prefrences
            sharedPreferences=mContext.getSharedPreferences("datakey",mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String getdata=sharedPreferences.getString("postkey", String.valueOf(myColor2));
            if(getdata!=null) {
                //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Data Value Already Set: "+myid+" Data"+getdata,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (getdata.equals(myid)) {
                  //  Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data Value Match: " + getdata, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageTypeViewHolder.title.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data Value Already Setting: " + getdata, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

           // Toast.makeText(mContext,"GET TOTAL DATA SIZE: "+dataset.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Set On Click Listner
            imageTypeViewHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    //imageTypeViewHolder.title.setTextColor(myColor2);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("postkey",object.id);
                    editor.apply();

                  String getdata=sharedPreferences.getString("postkey","No Data");



                    if(getdata!=null){

                       // Toast.makeText(mContext,"Data Value"+getdata,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }else{
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Data Value is Null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, WPPostDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("itemPosition",position);

                    intent.putExtra("link",object.link);

                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


        } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public static class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title,subtitle,link,date,id;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ImageTypeViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            this.title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.link=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.link);
            this.subtitle=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            this.imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            this.date=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            this.id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset == null ? 0 : dataset.size();
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        isLoading = false;
    }

    private class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<Model> newList){
        dataset=new ArrayList<>();
        dataset.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqh0C.png) of Error:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a `null` in `list`, or a `Model` object whose title is `null`.

Since I spotted this:

```
 list.add(null);
```

it is probably the former.

Now I haven't looked at *why* you are adding `null` to the list, but it is probably a bad design choice.  Not least because it means you will need to test each element for null before you try to use it.